# No me cargan la imagenes en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo la siguiente linea, que lo que debería hacer es ir a la base de datos y cargarme las imágenes pero no me carga la imagen, el campo de la imagen tiene una url que es donde se encuentra la imagen :

```
<img src="{{ $product->featured_image_url }}" alt="Thumbnail Image" class="img-raised rounded-circle">
```

Cuando voy a inspeccionar el código en el explorador me aparece

```
img src(unknow)
```

Comment: que contiene `$product->featured_image_url`? podrias hacer un `dd($product->featured_image_url)` en el controller antes de llamar la vista para saber que viene en ese atributo.

Comment: lo hace es leer la direccion web de la imagen pero no me aparece

Comment: Debes agregar mas detalles a tu pregunta. Revisa [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: Hola Agustin, ¿Nos puedes enseñar algunas de las URLs que suelta `$product->featured_image_url`, queremos ver como esta formada la URL para poder ayudarte.

Comment: asi es como tengo una de las images guardadas https://lorempixel.com/250/250/?46424 en la base de datos, como dije al inspeccionar el codigo me aparece "<img src(unknow) alt="Thumbnail Image" class="img-raised rounded-circle">"

Answer (score 0):

por ahora resolvi el problema, tuve que cambiar el codigo del src de la etiqueta image:

asi quedo

```
src="$product->images()->first()->image"
```

Comment: aun asi esta mal, deberias de usar helper como `asset` si no quieres tener problemas futuros